# How to test the payload by mocking POST request in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, pytest

I have a function that sends some payload to an external API using `requests.post()` method. I want to test whether the payload satisfies certain conditions in the tests. Based on that, I need to mock requests post and capture the payload in the testing function. Ideally, I don't want to add another external dependency and just stick to pytest but it is flexible if there are no other ways.

There are a few questions like this but they don't explore the similar use-case so they are not helpful.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
def mock_request_post(**kwargs):
    # check if kwargs satisfy test conditions

def test_api(args):
    # mock requests module with `mock_request_post`
    # make api call
```

Comment: Write fixtures in conftest.py and use them in testing functions. Fixture can mock a valid payload, invalid one or malformed it's quite flexible. You pass them to the test as the argument

Comment: Can you share an example for fixture of requests module

Comment: I can also suggest you to take a look at library called [`responses`](https://pypi.org/project/responses/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mock requests. Keeping your code as it is and adding it, you'll get something like this

```
import requests
import requests_mock

def mock_request_post(request, context):
    # check if request satisfies test conditions
    assert request.text == "mock"

def test_api(requests_mock):
    # mock requests module with `mock_request_post`
    requests_mock.post("http://my-api", text=mock_request_post)
    # make api call
    requests.post("http://my-api", data="mock")
    # verify
    assert requests_mock.request_history[0].text == "mock"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the **unittest.mock** library that comes with Python? It has the capability to mock the **requests.post** method and capture the payload during your tests.

You can check if this works:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import your_module  # Import the module containing your API function

# Define your test conditions here
def satisfy_test_conditions(payload):
    # Implement your conditions here
    # For example, check if payload has a certain key or value
    return True  # Replace with your condition

def mock_request_post(*args, **kwargs):
    # Simulate a successful API request and capture the payload
    payload = kwargs.get('data', None)

    # Check if the payload satisfies your test conditions
    if satisfy_test_conditions(payload):
        # Return a mock response object
        response = Mock()
        response.status_code = 200
        response.json.return_value = {"message": "Mock response"}
        return response
    else:
        # Return a mock response object for failure
        response = Mock()
        response.status_code = 400
        response.json.return_value = {"message": "Invalid payload"}
        return response

# Use the pytest fixture to mock requests.post
@pytest.fixture
def mock_post_request():
    with patch('requests.post', side_effect=mock_request_post):
        yield

# Your test function
def test_api(mock_post_request):
    # Call your API function that sends the payload
    response = your_module.send_payload_to_api({'key': 'value'})

    # Assert that the response or behavior is as expected
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Mock response"}

# Run the tests with pytest
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

In the above code, **mock_request_post** mocks the **requests.post** method. It captures the payload and checks if it satisfies your test conditions.

And **mock_post_request** fixture patches **requests.post** during the test. This makes sure that the mock version of **requests.post** is used within the **test_api** function.

In the **test_api** function, you can call your API function and then assert that the response or behavior is as expected based on your test conditions.

And then, run the tests using pytest.